# Should I ask for relocation reimbursement just after joining?

Tags: hiring-process, relocation

Soon I would be relocating to a new place. As per the company offer letter I am eligible for relocation allowance. For sake of currency conversion, I want that my company pays me the amount just after I join, so that I can pay for my accommodation (advance rent or any such expense).

Will that be rude if I ask my employer for reimbursing the relocation amount just after joining?

Additional Information:

- I accepted the offer letter seeing the relocation benefits. My question is when to ask, should I wait for the first salary or can I ask in advance?
- The amount is fixed and is Tax free
- The location I am moving is Amsterdam, The Netherlands

Comment: location information is important. For example in the US relocation reimbursement has to follow IRS regulations regarding what they can cover, and what receipts are needed to avoid the money being taxable.

Comment: I'd probably ask before moving just to be clear on what would and wouldn't be covered, but that's my 2 cents on this.

Comment: Related question [here](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/8996/2322)

Comment: Please define "relocation allowance" for those not acquainted with it. Is this a one-time compensation for your reloaction/moving costs, or a continuous salary increase as compensation for the fact that you move to another place? Depending on the answer, the **moment** of your additional expenses differs, and hence, so should the moment of compensation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Will that be rude if I ask my employer for reimbursing the relocation
>   amount just after joining?

It's not rude - but don't wait that long. Ask now.

Since you know you will use it, and have some concerns about early expenses, ask about the terms of the relocation allowance *before* you join.

That way, you can understand what they will and won't do, and have a chance to modify your accommodation plans accordingly.

Comment: +1:  IMO, at least, this is the sort of thing to ask *before* you accept an offer.

Comment: Joe, sorry if that came across poorly.  I didn't mean to be critical, I just mentioned that for future viewers of this particular Q&A.

Answer (score 3):

From your question, your company has already agreed to pay you relocation expenses, but hasn't been explicit about how much, or what will be reimbursed. Now is the time to ask them for details. Find out if it is a fixed sum, or if they reimburse you for certain expenses. I'm assuming your question is about when you can apply to get the actual money, not when you ask if they will pay.

Normally businesses reimburse you for expenses after you have paid for them - that way they can be sure you have actually paid for them. With relocation expenses they are especially careful about this, because if you suddenly say "Hey guys, I've decided not to work for your company after all" its very difficult for them to get their money back.

It's perfectly fine to ask on day one of your employment for reimbursement of *any expenses you've already paid* (like moving costs). However be aware that actually getting the money can take weeks, depending on the company. If you can't afford to pay for things like deposits on apartments it's OK to ask for an *advance* on expenses. It might be tricky to get before you start work, but should be fine after that.

If they have agreed to pay you a fixed sum, rather than reimburse actual expenses, it should be fine to ask for that on day one also.

Comment: Yes, they have specified me a fixed amount. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I absolutely agree to your point stating the company perspective (if I say them "Hey guys, I've decided not to work for your company after all"). However as I would be getting fixed amount I would prefer asking them just after joining.